# The application has stopped unexpectedly. force close appears after click a button

Tags: android-emulator

The application has stopped unexpectedly. force close. this message comes only for one intent after clicking 'update'button, for another intents the app works fine. The app is to take two string inputs and update them to database and view the table. My app is updating perfectly but when i click to view it comes up with the error message.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_NAME + "(" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

    );


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

}

public hotornot(Context c){
ourcontext = c;
}
public hotornot open(){
ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourcontext);
ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;
}
public void close(){
ourHelper.close();
}
public Long createentry(String name, String hotness){
ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS,hotness );
return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
    public String getdata() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String[] columns = new String[]  {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,      null);
String result = "";
int irow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
int iname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
int ihotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);
for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
{
    result = result + c.getString(irow) + " " + c.getString(iname) + " " + c.getString(ihotness) + "\n";

}
return result;
}
}
```

Here is the updated manifest file:

```
07-24 17:31:05.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting      due to uncaught exception
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=org.sqlite.SVIEW }
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at org.sqlite.sqliteexample.onClick(sqliteexample.java:75)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-24 17:31:05.164: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(203):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception stack shows that the error is due to the table (peopletable) not being present.

A quick glance at your code shows the following:

`db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_NAME + "(" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"`

The error is probably due to a typo in your code. You are using `DATABASE_NAME` instead of `DATABASE_TABLE` in your code, as a result of which your table name is different from the one that the rest of your code is expecting.

Comment: I have  checked it. It is still not working. I have updated my manifest file... have a look..